# Access argument of top function

Tags: javascript

I want access argument of top function . Here is my code :

```
 function(data){ // i want access this argument

 logger.info(data.Description,data.Title,clickNotiCustomer)
})

function clickNotiCustomer(){ //here is function run when I click 
                     $http.post('/feeds/clearOneNoti',{id:data._id}).then(()=>{
                        window.location.href = data.Link;
                    })

}
```

But It not work . I get this error : data is not defined . How can I solve this . Please help me

Comment: Is that top function an anonymous function? If not, how is it defined?

Comment: The `data` in `function(data)` is a *function parameter* and not globally defined. Thus you will not be able to access it outside of that function.

Comment: it is data of ajax callback

Comment: @LambdaNinja is it possible to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the top function is an ajax callback, you can save the variable in a globally-scoped variable to access it from the second function. i.e.:

Global scope:

```
var ajaxData;
```

First function:

```
function(data){
  logger.info(data.Description,data.Title,clickNotiCustomer)

  // assign global variable to data
  ajaxData = data;
}
```

Second function:

```
$http.post('/feeds/clearOneNoti',{id:data._id}).then(()=>{
  // accessing global variable ajaxData
  window.location.href = ajaxData.Link;
})
```

For more info look into [variable scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope).